# Можно ли здесь применить array_multisort?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив

```
$array = array(
    'bob' => array('val' => 'три',  'num' => 3),
    'ken' => array('val' => 'два',  'num' => 2),
    'sam' => array('val' => 'один', 'num' => 1),
);
```

Можно ли отвортировать его по значению ключа num используя функцию array_multisort? Сохранять ключи bob, ken, sam не обязательно. Должен получиться результат:

```
$array = array(
    '0' => array('val' => 'один', 'num' => 1),
    '1' => array('val' => 'два',  'num' => 2),
    '2' => array('val' => 'три',  'num' => 3),
);
```

Comment: `array_multisort(array_column($arr, 'num'), $arr)`